# When turning in a mission, do you have to be on the mission hex to complete a mission, or is anywhere in the system acceptable?

Tags: xia

In Xia, Legends of a Drift System, one can receive missions to go to certain locations and do such things as conduct negotiations or pick up contraband.  In order to achieve this step of this mission, is it necessary to go to that system's "mission" location, or is it sufficient to enter that system's tile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you must go to the mission point (!) to complete a mission.

Source: http://www.faroffgames.com/images/games/xia-legends-of-a-drift-system/Xia_Rulebook.pdf

Look at the top left section of page 14

Comment: Also, look at the card: it will say something like "**Delivery:** TK-429 (!)". The (!) is the symbol for the mission hex, so that's where you need to go to finish the mission.